# Differences between Kryo.Serializer and TypeSerializer

Tags: apache-flink, kryo

If I need to implement a custom serializer for my (keyed) state objects, what are the pros/cons of `Kryo.Serializater` vs `TypeSerializer`. For instance, the interface for the latter is more complicated, so it seems that `Kryo.Serializer` should be always preferred solely based on this. What advantages could the `Kryo.Serializer` have over the Kryo one? It is maybe more performant, justifying the more complicated interface? In summary, when is one option preferred over the other.

Comment: I think you'll find this blog post on choosing a serializer helpful: https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html.

Comment: Thanks David I was indeed taking a look now, perfect timing!